# Initialize a member of two dimensional dynamic struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am initializing a dynamic 2-dimensional struct in C like this:

```
typedef struct
    {
        int v;
        unsigned int t;
    } cb;
    cb **b;
b = malloc( sizeof(*b) * s + (s * (e * sizeof(**b) )));
```

s and e are dimensions of the array(row and column size)

How do I also initialize b with v set as 0?

Comment: First you have to decide, C or C++. Answer will be different. Then, this is not 2D but only an emulation of it. Don't do that, neither in C nor C++. In C you can just do `a (*b)[dim2] = malloc(sizeof(a[dim1][dim2]));` and you have it in one go.

Comment: @sergej e and j are the dimensions. Vertical and Horizontal. I'll edit my question.

Comment: You can initialize v to zero by replacing malloc with calloc.

Comment: Will the array be used locally in a function? If so, you can just write `cb arr[s][e];` to create it. (It should be reasonably small too, to fit on the stack.)

Answer (score 2):

Never use pointer-to-pointer lookup tables for the purpose of dynamically allocating 2D arrays. It is widespread but bad and incorrect practice, leading to segmentation and slow programs.

Instead, use an array pointer and allocate a true 2D array in adjacent memory:

```
cb (*arr)[y] = malloc( sizeof(cb[x][y]) );

arr[i][j] = something;

free(arr);
```

To initialize everything to zero, use calloc instead of malloc. To initialize everything to a given value, you have to use a loop and assign values one by one.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more on this?

Comment: @Maxsteel `arr` is a pointer to a "cb array" of size `y`. You set it to point to the first element of a 2D "cb array" of size `x` times `y`. Since the rules of pointer arithmetic apply to array pointers just as any other pointer, `arr[i]` will give you array number `i`, just as `int* ptr; ptr[i]` will give you `int` number `i`. And since `arr[i]` is an array, `arr[i][j]` is an item of that array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `calloc` instead of using `malloc`.